# Use the Central Limit Theorem to calculate the approx probabilities of Gamma RVs?

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution, central-limit-theorem

If $X_i, i=1,...,$ are independent, identically distributed $\operatorname{N}(0,1)$ random variables, and $Y_i = X_i^2$ are independent $\operatorname{Gamma}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ RVs, use the Central Limit Theorem to calculate the approximate values of the probabilities:
$\sum_{1}^{50} {Y_i \gt 40}$ and $\sum_{1}^{50} {Y_i \lt 60}$ 
I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Hi Mathlete, this appears to be standard bookwork and looks like it's probably related to some course. Would you mind adding the `self-study` tag please? \[You might like to read through the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) item relating to `homework` (a synonym for `self-study`) and the [self study tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for a description of how those questions are dealt with. In particular, there are some expectations of both askers and answerers that differ slightly from the other kinds of questions.\]

Comment: Because $E(Y_i)=E(X_i^2)=E((X_i-0)^2)$ is the variance of $X_i$, clearly the mean of $Y_i$ is $1$. Because $E((Y_i-1)^2)=E(Y_i^2)-2E(Y_i)+E(1)=E(X_i^4)-2+1=2$, the variance of $Y_i$ is $2$. That's all you need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of semesters since the delta method, so bear with me here.

What does the CLT tell us?

$\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{x}-\mu)}{\sigma} \rightarrow N(0,1)$

You can use the delta method to determine the asymptotic distribution of $X^2$.

$\sqrt{n}(g(X_n) - g(\mu)) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2(g'(\mu))^2)$

So you need to set your $g(X)$, in this case $X^2$. $g(\mu) = \mu^2$.  you know the distribution of $X^2$ so you know what the $\sigma^2$ is.  From there you should be able to turn this into a N(0,1) and use z-tables to figure out what the probability of $\Sigma Y_i > 40$ and  $\Sigma Y_i < 60$.  Hope this helps.

Comment: So I would get $\sqrt{n}$$(X_n^2)$ -> $N(0,(g'(0))^2)$ How would I follow on from there?

Comment: Considering I get $g'(\mu)=0$ have I done something wrong?

Comment: no. $g(\mu) = \mu^2$ so $g'(\mu) = 2\mu$, $g'(\mu)^2$ = $4\mu^2$

Comment: Yes but my mean is 0?

Comment: Or would it be 1/2?

Comment: http://bmbolstad.com/teaching/Stat215b/Lab4/delta_method.pdf  Here are a few examples on how to carry out the delta method and get a normal distribution asymptotically.  Hope this helps.  Once you've seen a few carried out, maybe you can solve this one.  Also, look at the wiki page for delta method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting confused because I've never encountered this method before.

Comment: Here's some more on the delta method.  It's certainly not super easy to understand, in my opinion. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme308/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf

Comment: I'm curious what methods you discussed in class to solve this sort of problem.

Comment: @ClarkW.Griswold my guess is they've probably just done the CLT, and haven't even mentioned the Delta method. The CLT is sufficient for this question.

Comment: I'm curious what answer you would obtain with your method, Clark, because I'm pretty sure it will be very wrong: the delta method not only is unnecessary, it is far too crude to solve this problem.  But I could be missing something because it's not clear what many of your symbols, such as $\mu$, really refer to.